# Gitlab CI / CD with Terraform + Python

Tags: gitlab-ci

On my Gitlab CI / CD, I have a terraform code that requires Python installed to use [an external module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-notify-slack).

When running `terraform plan` via Gitlab pipelines, I get the following error:

```
 module.notify_slack.module.lambda.data.aws_caller_identity.current[0]: Refreshing state...
 Error: can't find external program "python3"
   on .terraform/modules/notify_slack.lambda/terraform-aws-lambda-1.6.0/package.tf line 3, in data "external" "archive_prepare":
    3: data "external" "archive_prepare" {
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What image do I need to use that contains Terraform and Python? Will I need to create my own docker image?

Comment: Can you share your .gitlab-ci.yml file, or the section for this job?  A simplified version of it would help too.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit of an old post, but I'll share my solution in case anyone else stumbles upon this problem too.

Choose an existing python image and install terraform manually - this seems to me to be the easiest solution, if pragmatism is important to you.

This is the relevant section of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
default:
  image: python:latest
  before_script:
    - python -V  # Display version for debugging purposes only
    - apt-get update -y
    - apt-get install unzip wget -y
    - wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip
    - unzip terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip
    - mv terraform /usr/local/bin/
    - terraform --version  # Display version for debugging purposes only
```

The environment variable was set up in the GitLab CI/CD settings, otherwise just change it for the specific version of Terraform you want.

I was pleasantly surprised at the speed in which this installation takes place, as this clearly isn't an optimal way to do it - the best performing runner will probably use your own custom image with all of your required dependencies pre-installed - I'll leave you to decide whether its worth it for your own purposes. Nonetheless, this solution doesn't appear to be prohibitively slow.

Comment: Although this is old it still works as of December 2022!

Comment: Great solution! Because my codebase has a directory named terraform I unzip directly to /usr/local/bin: unzip -d /usr/local/bin/ terraform_1.3.9_linux_amd64.zip